# DB2 Trigger checks after insert

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a trigger for only some checks.
But when I declared it as
`BEFORE INSERT`, the constraint checks are made after trigger checks.
`AFTER INSERT`, the constraint checks are made before trigger checks.

But I am not sure if the second approach is the correct way, especially when I have many insert triggers defined for this table?

Comment: "if the second approach is the correct way" to check ... what exactly?

Comment: Meaning what about the other triggers on the same table. Are they also executed when one of them violated, when changing to `AFTER`? And can I assume that the commit was made after the trigger checks?

Comment: Triggers on a table are executed in the order of their creation time. There is no such meaning as "trigger violation". If some uncaught exception appears in some trigger, the whole statement fired this trigger returns the corresponding error. Commits or rollbacks are not allowed in triggers.